# Infinite loading when calling the QnAMaker using WebMethod C#

Tags: c#, azure, web-services, azure-qna-maker

When I tried to call the web method "QnAMakerQuestionsAnswers", It will only have an infinite loading and will not show the result. I have tried this in a console application and it works perfectly but not for the WebMethod. I am not sure which part of my code I need to modify but this is a little bit frustrating. Please help!!
Code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ChatbotWebService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for ChatbotWebService
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class ChatbotWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        // NOTE: Replace this with a valid host name.
        static string host = "<Host Name>";

        // NOTE: Replace this with a valid endpoint key.
        // This is not your subscription key.
        // To get your endpoint keys, call the GET /endpointkeys method.
        static string endpoint_key = "<End Point Key>";

        // NOTE: Replace this with a valid knowledge base ID.
        // Make sure you have published the knowledge base with the
        // POST /knowledgebases/{knowledge base ID} method.
        static string kb = "<KB ID>";

        static string service = "/qnamaker";
        static string method = "/knowledgebases/" + kb + "/generateAnswer/";

        static string question = @"
        {
            'question': 'Who are you?'
        }
        ";

        async static Task<string> Post(string uri, string body)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
            {
                request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
                request.RequestUri = new Uri(uri);
                request.Content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "EndpointKey " + endpoint_key);
                //SUPER IMPORTANT LINE. PLEASE DO IT FOR .NET Framework v4.5.
                //Explanation at https://blogs.perficient.com/2016/04/28/tsl-1-2-and-net-support/
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }

        }

        async static Task<string> GetAnswers()
        {
            var uri = host + service + method;
            Console.WriteLine("Calling " + uri + ".");
            string response = "NULL";
            try
            {
                response = await Post(uri, question);
                Console.WriteLine(response);
                Console.WriteLine("Press any enter to continue.");
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException.Message);
            }
            return response;

        }
        [WebMethod]
        public string QnAMakerQuestionsAnswers()
        {
            return GetAnswers().Result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I get the same issue, even when trying to use another library for making the HTTP request, as you say it works with a console app, it sounds like some kind of incompatibility with WebMethods. I think it it worth raising an issue with the QnA Maker team on the [official GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices). That said, are you limited to a Web Service, or could you use something like Web API or an Azure Function to achieve what you want?

Comment: Hey @MattStannett , I'll raise an issue on that. I think anything is fine except Azure Functions. I prefer uploading my code to an ASP.NET Web Server and calling it through the web server. I guess my other solution is C# Web API?

Comment: I have tried using Web API, same error. I cannot get the response from my localhost.

Comment: Interesting, I've uploaded a Web API project [here](https://github.com/BeigeBadger/QnAMaker-WebAPI) that worked with my KB, the code of interest is in the HomeController.

Comment: It still says error. "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond <IP Address>"                          And error in Line 31: "var response = await client.SendAsync(request);" I have also changed the .NET framework to 4.5.2. I do not have access to .NET framework of 4.7.2.

Comment: I have also found out that the requirement for qnamaker REST api is visual studio 2017, which requires .NET framework of more than 4.6. Then the only solution is to migrate to 4.6 or above.

Comment: .NET Core is another option, it might even be less pain that trying to upgrade a .NET framework version in a production environment which has other things depending on it.

Comment: I have tested using .NET framework 4.7.2 from your project as indicated above. It still has the same error. "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond <IP Address>". Not really sure how to handle this problem.. Trying to find other alternatives

Comment: @MattStannett May I know your development tools: VS Studio Version, IIS version and .NET framework and Core versions.

Comment: The version details for my development environment are [here](https://i.imgur.com/IlAmSL3.png). I am using VS 2019 Enterprise. I have uploaded a [PostMan](https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/) collection [here](https://ufile.io/4irls3hg) with a sample request which will query my KB. Import it (File > Import) then check against my KB to see if it is maybe something with your environment, then if it works, try replacing my details in the URL and headers.

Comment: I think it is still my environment. I might need to upgrade to VS 2019 to make the project working. Will update you later if it works on VS 2019

Comment: I was using VS2019 and still had issues with using web services. Web API did work though. Have you had a response on the issue that you opened?

Comment: I have tested using VS 2019 on your code which you uploaded to Github using my QnAMaker Service (endpoint key, kb key, hostname). It still shows the same error. "Connection attempt failed...". Does it effect if I am using the free tier for QnAMaker service?

Comment: Ah yes, I have deleted that KB, sorry. The tier you're using shouldn't matter. Double check the endpoint key, hostname, and kb id are correct. Also see my comment above about Postman, download that tool and the postman collection, then edit it to have your details for the URL and headers to see if it works.

Comment: I have tested it in two environments. Intranet and Internet, internet works but intranet doesnt work. Think the intranet might block some of the packets. Thank you for helping!

Comment: No problem, glad you got the issue narrowed down.

Comment: @MattStannett I have used web api dotnet framework 4.7.2 and proxy(to connect to internet). When I call the post method which calls the QnAMaker Service, the operation will timed out which I do not know why. I tried using dotnet core and it works fine but not for dotnet framework. Can you try calling your dotnet framework web api using the post method? (Postman or console)

Comment: I tested with a .NET WCF project and was not able to reproduce the issue myself. Are you able to get a fiddler/har trace of the issue? I'm curious to see what that would contain to help isolate that error. You can compare the request against one done in Postman or console app to see what the difference may be across the wire.

Comment: @Reynold Did you get any further on this? Are you still able to reproduce the error? If so, can you provide me with the current information to reproduce it?